# 32Bit linking using pcl under os x 10.9

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

i have been coming up with quite a strange think. I am getting the following error when compiling my program using os x 10.9 and the pcl:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
"pcl::OpenNIGrabber::OpenNIGrabber(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, pcl::OpenNIGrabber::Mode const&, pcl::OpenNIGrabber::Mode
const&)", referenced from:
```

I know that i am not the only one who had this error, but unfortunately nothing has helped so far. The thing is, i had exactly the same error on my windows machine, and i fixed it by installing the 32bit version of pcl.

So, is there any way to compile pcl in 32bit code using my mac? It would be really great. Btw i already gave the following a try, but failed:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=386
```

what follows:

```
clang: error: invalid arch name '-arch 386'
```

I would be really greatfull if anybody could give a hint on how to solve this problem.

Best wishes

Comment: That architecture should be **i386**, not 386 (at least on my mac)

Comment: Are you defining a templates class with the functions declared in a cpp file by chance?

Comment: No I am just treating an OpenNIGrabber object in my main.cpp:
    
 pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber();